# Select a nullable bit with a default value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, bit

I need to select a nullable bit column in a view, but use a default value of FALSE whenever the value is NULL.  (For other reasons, I can't add the default value on the source table itself.)  Here is what I am doing.

```
CAST 
(
    CASE 
    WHEN bit_column IS NULL THEN 0 
    ELSE bit_column  
END 
    AS BIT
) AS bit_column,
...
```

I have to do this on four columns, so I'm wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the isnull function.

```
isnull(bit_column, 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT coalesce(bit_column,0) bit_column
```

Comment: What datatype will be sent to the client? int or bit?

Comment: A bit will be sent to the client.

Comment: Good question, I researched it and found this link: http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html From there, "COALESCE works more like a CASE expression, which returns a single datatype depending on precendence and accommodating all possible outcomes". So I'm not sure. But on the client side, 0 or 1 will fit in either a bit or an int, so I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  It appears that since I always want the result to have the datatype of the first parameter, I should use ISNULL.  ISNULL also allows me to see True or False (preferred over 1 or 0) when I browse the view in SQL Server Management Studio.  So I am going to accept the ISNULL answer.  However, I can see many situations where COALESCE is a better choice.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: `SELECT coalesce(bit_column, cast(0 as bit)) bit_column`

Comment: @Shannon Severance: that is just too far to avoid ISNULL

Comment: @gbn: That's why it's a comment and not an answer. But knowing another option can't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For T-SQL use

```
SELECT coalesce(bit_column, cast(0 as bit)) bit_column
```

In a code example,

```
 , examStatus.text
 , COALESCE(examStatus.archived, cast(0 as bit))
```

If examStatus.archived is NULL it will default to **0** (aka false)